# Как изменить цвет ToggleButton в Андроид?

Tags: android, button, color

По умолчанию (по крайней мере, у меня) кнопка `ToggleButton` имеет тёмно-серый цвет, индикатор включения (полоска внизу) - почти чёрный.

При нажатии на кнопку она кратковременно подсвечивается ярко-синим, индикатор становится ярко-синим.

При изменении свойства `background` меняется цвет всей кнопки, включая индикатор. И никакой подсветки при нажатии.

*Вопрос:* как изменить цвет кнопки, не затрагивая индикатор, и чтоб осталась цветовая реакция на нажатие?

Ну и, если возможно, изменить цвет индикатора..

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте так

создаете файл `colors.xml` в папке `res/values`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

В папке `drawable`, создается файл `my_btn_toggle.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/red"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/green"  />
</selector>
```

и в `xml` добавляем `ToggleButton` в виде:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_btn_toggle
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978993/4953620)

---

есть вариант создать свой ToggleButton

файл  `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#d1d4d4"
    >
    <!-- ToggleButton по умолчанию -->
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <!-- ToggleButton наш -->
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:layout_below="@id/toggle"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

файл `res/drawable/toggle_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_state_on"
        android:state_checked="true"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_state_off"
        android:state_checked="false"
        />
</selector>
```

файл `res/drawable/toggle_state_on.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- 5dp border вокруг фигуры -->
            <stroke
                android:color="#4c975d"
                android:width="5dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Переписать левую, верхную, правую стороны с фоном нашего цвета  -->
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#6dd988"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

файл `res/drawable/toggle_state_off.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- 5dp border вокруг фигуры -->
            <stroke
                android:color="#b1113e"
                android:width="5dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Переписать левую, верхную, правую стороны с фоном нашего цвета -->
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f51354"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

результат будет примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[источник](http://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-togglebutton-style.html)

Comment: Результатом Вашего примера является изменение цвета всей кнопки. При этом - 1) потерян индикатор 2) нет кратковременного (эффект вспышки) изменения цвета при нажатии.

Comment: @santfos, ну тогда рисуйте две иконки кнопки и назначайте их вместо цветов.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Слева - кнопка по умолчанию, справа - как нужно.
Можно, конечно, нарисовать свои изображения, создать собственный элемент...
Неужели нет простой возможности изменить цвет фона, не затрагивая полоску-индикатор???